# apply different color with theme in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have two data templates in my design page as "IncomingMessageTemplate" and "OutgoingMessageTemplate" in windows phone page like this

```
         <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="12" >
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    ..... .... any content 
              </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
```

I need to apply different color to one data template.But i cannot give static different color(something like "Red"...)as user can change the theme.So here my concern is user can change the theme according to their wish..But need to change the "OutgoingMessageTemplate" to some other than the theme color.. and the "IncomingMessageTemplate" is the theme color.. Is it possible.. can any one help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to override the theme selected by the user, but you have to write some code to manage this. Se this blog post [Windows Phone Mango Custom application Theme Step by Step](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/windows-phone-mango-custom-application-theme-step-by-step). It is allso posible to force only dark theme or light theme.